# Which is Highest Content Level of Academic Papers: Chapter or Section?

Tags: writing, formatting

Is there a rule or common agreement on which one to use on Academic Papers?

- Chapters > Sections > Subsections ...; or simply
- Sections > Subsections > ... ?

Is it the case that *chapters* are used in books and thesis, and everything else start with *sections*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it the case that chapters are used in books and thesis, and everything else start with sections?

I don't know what you mean by *everything else*, but in general, **yes.** Academic papers and articles generally have a section-subsection structure, with books and theses having a chapter-section-subsection structure. Most journals you submit to will insist on the section-subsection structure.

Comment: For completeness: books and theses might also have *parts* as a superstructure for multiple chapters.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper And long papers.  I've also seen long papers have chapters, but that's a bit unusual.

Comment: Thank you so much. It also just occurred to me to also check the `latex` template sample document for the conference, which uses `section` as mentioned in this answer.